# What kinds of variables should we use the normality test for?

Tags: hypothesis-testing, normality-assumption

When should we apply normality tests? For which types of the variables should we apply the normality test?
For example dependent variables, independent variables, or control variables, etc?

Comment: Readers here may find this thread of interest: [what-if-residuals-are-normally-distributed-but-y-is-not](http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/12262/).

Answer (score 6):

In many contexts (e.g., multiple regression) it is the distribution of the residuals that is the relevant assumption (see [here for a discussion](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/12053/what-should-i-check-for-normality-raw-data-or-residuals)).

Your question also raises the general issue of the relevance of normality testing. See this previous question:
[Is normality testing 'essentially useless'?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/2492/is-normality-testing-essentially-useless)

However, more broadly, doing exploratory data analysis (e.g., plots, summary statistics, etc.) to understand the distribution of all your variables is important.

Comment: I agree with Jeromy. There is no sense to categorize application of normality testing in terms of types of variables. What matters is when normality becomes a modeling issue. There are many pros and cons associated with normality testing that are discussed in other posts on this site including the one Jeromy mentioned.

Comment: +1 for "However, more broadly, doing exploratory data analysis (e.g., plots, summary statistics, etc.) to understand the distribution of all your variables is important".