# QQ plot result doesn't correspond to normality test

Tags: r, regression, anova, qq-plot, shapiro-wilk-test

I am considering an ANOVA model for such data:

```
Student    Class  Points on exam   Day of studying
1           P1       12             Day 10
2           P3       23             Day 5
3           P3       8              Day 1
4           P2       36             Day 10
5           P1       10             Day 1
6           P2       86             Day 10
7           P1       13             Day 5
...
```

and such ANOVA model:

```
model <- aov(Points ~ Class + Day, data)
ggqqplot(residuals(model))
```

how can I check if this model **satisfies the normality of distribution?** (other than the Q-Q plot of the model?)

[image: QQ-Plot]

**My Q-Q plot of the model (above) seems to show normal distribution but when I perform Shapiro-Wilk( that considers only Points) the p-value comes out incredibly small... Therefore I don't know if I can assume the normality or not.**

```
Shapiro-Wilk normality test

data:  Points
W = 0.92212, p-value = 9.97e-13
```

Comment: "*My Q-Q plot of the model (above) seems to show normal distribution*". **Does it?**

Comment: The only normal quantile plot of interest here is of the residuals. Is that what you are showing. A plot of the "model" could be many things. (I am not a routine R user but in any case if I understand correctly you don't show the syntax used to produce the plot.

Comment: @NickCox you are right! I updated the question

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. So, compare like with like: Shapiro-Wilk on the residuals will I guess reject overwhelmingly too, but that doesn't mean much. The real issue is whether these results point to a different analysis, which I doubt. You have `Points` and at least 3 classes and at least 3 days. Unless the distribution of `Points` is. conditional, on predictor, very skewed I doubt there is a strong case for doing anything different. The threads cited by @Tim are helpful here.

Answer (score 8):

- Your Q-Q plot *does not* show that the data is normally distributed. In fact, [it shows](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/101274/how-to-interpret-a-qq-plot) that the distribution diverges from Gaussian (values lower than -1 and higher than 1.5 diverge from the diagonal dashed line). See also the [Interpreting QQplot - Is there any rule of thumb to decide for non-normality?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/111010/interpreting-qqplot-is-there-any-rule-of-thumb-to-decide-for-non-normality/111013#111013) thread.
- You may be also interested in the [Is normality testing 'essentially useless'?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/2492/is-normality-testing-essentially-useless) thread. Are those normality tests really needed? [Likely not.](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/12074/35989)

Answer (score 4):

Just on first look, this distribution looks very short tailed, as you can see it looks kind of like this simulation with a uniform distribution
[image: simulation with a uniform distribution]