# Query re Normal Distribution of Data for GLM

Tags: anova, residuals, assumptions

Ive collected data for force measurements (response variable) based on 3 factors in unique tests

1. material type (2 off) (I assume this is categorical)
2. tool radius (2 off) (assume this is discrete as its not continuous)
3. tool rake angle (3 off)

I have 4 to 5 repetitions per unique test

The response variable data as in. the measured forces (all of it) does not follow a normal distribution. See Normal Distribution plot of the Response data in Image

[image: normal distribution plot for force data]

I have read that a requirement for use of GLM is that the data must be normally distributed.  I assume this to mean the response data, but have read in the some books and reference material (incl Minitab information on Anova) that it means residuals.

So I need to ask

1. Can I use a GLM to analyse data when the pooled response data does not follow a normal distribution IF
   as it appears the residuals appear to follow a normal distribution (image below from the GLM analysis), see below

[image: plot of residuals from GLM]

If this is the case it means I do not need to transfer the data which is better.

2. Do I need to use residuals or standardised residuals, or does it matter?

Thanks

GTK

Comment: Hi GTK! Normal assumption is about the residuals, see [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/33320/32477) and [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/12053/what-should-i-check-for-normality-raw-data-or-residuals) for example? Second, what do you mean by GLM? General Linear Models or Generalized Linear Models?

Comment: Since you said you used Minitab it seems you are referring to [General Linear Models](https://support.minitab.com/en-us/minitab/21/help-and-how-to/statistical-modeling/anova/supporting-topics/basics/what-is-a-general-linear-model/). Many people associate GLMs with Generalized Linear Models. See @Dave 's answer.

Comment: I should say Im not very proficient in Stats.  I have a set of responses with some factors my objective was to check if the factors (1 categorical 3 levels) and the other 2 factors I would describe as ordinal have 4 levels. I decided to use a General Linear Model in Minitab as it provided the option of doing an ANOVA on this many factors to see if the factors and crossing them have a statistically significant effect on the response.   My main concern was to make sure to not violate any assumptions for the ANOVA with the general linear model in Minitab. Thanks All. I need a basic crash course.

Comment: @GTK you have explicitly selected the `generalized-linear-model` tag (confirming the impression many statisticians would have that this is what you meant by "GLM").  If you intend to discuss *general* linear models, please remove the `generalized-linear-model` tag and replace any instance of GLM with *general linear model*. It will reduce confusion over the intent of your post.

Comment: Your residuals vs fitted shows a clear pattern (nonlinear lack of fit). You should NOT be attempting to interpret the other diagnostic plots (including QQ plots and histograms) while that clear pattern is present, since that will impact the impression of each of the other plots away from what information you hope to extract from them.

Answer (score 2):

The general linear model **doesn't** assume the *data* are distributed Gaussian. To compute p values for such a model we do assume that the response is **conditionally** distributed Gaussian. This conditionality is on the model. We assume that each observation is a draw from a Gaussian distribution with its own mean but shared variance.

$$y_i \sim N(\mu_i, \sigma^2)$$

Note that the $i$th response data point is assumed to come from a Gaussian distribution with mean $\mu_i$ that is specific to that data point.

Our model is what gives us the estimates $\mu_i$, as a linear combination of weighted covariate values

$$\mu_i = \beta_0 + \beta_1 x_{1i} + \beta_2 x_{2i} + \cdots \beta_k x_{ki}$$

where the right hand side of the equation is the linear predictor, the $\beta_k$ are the model coefficients, the estimated effects of the covariates $\mathbf{x}_k$ on the response. In the general linear model the fitted values $\hat{y}_i$ are equal to $\mu_i$.

As for your diagnostic plots, the upper right plot of the standardized residuals indicates a problem; the spread of the residuals increases with the value of the linear predictor (the larger the fitted value the greater the spread). This would be a violation of the homogeneity assumption. Remember this

$$y_i \sim N(\mu_i, \sigma^2)$$

and my stating that each observation is distributed Gaussian with it's own mean $\mu_i$ but common variance $\sigma^2$? It is this last bit that is violated by your model/data. The variance isn't roughly the same for all your observations. So I would say that the model has problems.

You use the initialism GLM to seemingly mean *general linear model*. Note that the GLM initialism is used for the **generalized** linear model. These two models are not the same thing. The *general* linear model is the combination of linear regression and ANOVA. A **generalized** linear model allows for the conditional distribution to be drawn from the exponential family of distributions, so it *includes* the general linear model as a special case (where the conditional distribution is Gaussian) but it allows for responses that are conditionally distributed Binomial, Poisson, Gamma, etc. This is what allows the generalized linear model to model data that aren't amenable to linear regression.

In your case, you might use a GLM (generalized) here to account for the heterogeneity (non constant variance) - perhaps via a Gamma GLM - or you might use weighted linear regression or generalized least squares (GLS) model. You might also just log or square root transform the response and fit the linear regression as that might also solve the heterogeneity issue, however now you would be modelling the expected value of the log of your response, not the expected value of the response. So consider that.

Standardized residuals take into account the assumed variance of the residuals; they are the raw residual divided by the standard deviation of the residuals scaled by the square root of the complement of the hat values. By standardizing them, you can see which observations might be poorly fitted as they would have standardized residuals greater than say 3 (the residual is 3 standard deviations away from the fitted value).

Comment: Hi Gavin, many thanks.  And it happens I have already have running also a Log10 transformation on the response data as I was concerned about the divergence of the data in the upper right graph. In reality Im just after P values but I wanted to avoid the problem of modelling response with Log10 as I hoped I might be able to do some prediction of original values with the derived model formula.  Im sorry about using the term GLM as that is what Minitab uses and I just stuck with the abbreviation, though I was aware it was different to the generalised linear model. Thanks GTK

Answer (score 0):

Generalized linear models are all about conditional distributions. When you make an assumption about normality, it is about the conditional distribution of $y$, conditioned on some values of the feature(s) $x$, being normal. Ditto for logistic regression making an assumption about conditional binomial distributions or Poisson regression being about conditional Poisson distributions.

At no point is the overall distribution of $y$ considered, and the features definitely are not assumed to have normality.

The reason authors will write that the residuals should be normal is because that is a way to check if the assumption of a normal conditional distribution is a good one. This is messier when you have other GLM distributions like binomial or Poisson.

Comment: Thanks Dave, I was not sure about this part o the conditional distribution so it is good to understand this.  Im using a General Linear model, sorry for the confusion.  Im conducting some ANOVA on my data sets which is mainly what Im after.  Regards GTK