# Power analysis of a secondary data set with a multi-level model

Tags: multilevel-analysis, statistical-power

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Power analysis for observational study of secondary data](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/29176/power-analysis-for-observational-study-of-secondary-data)

I want to conduct a power analysis of a dataset that has already been collected. I have 350 participants in five regions, with six predictors and three control variables, and my dependent variable is binary. Can anyone tell me how I can conduct a power analysis using STATA?

Comment: What is the purpose of doing a power analysis after the data has been collected?  At this point you might as well do the analysis.  The purpose of power analysis is to determine whether or not the sample size is adequate for the goal of the study.

Comment: This is a functionally similar question, http://stats.stackexchange.com/q/29176/1036