# Questions about G*Power

Tags: correlation, spss, standard-deviation, sample-size, statistical-power

Since I found an insignificant result, I performed a power calculation in G*Power. But I am not entirely sure if I input the right number in some fields.
My design is a 2(between Ss) x 2(between Ss) design, so I have 2 variables, 4 different conditions (20 participants in each one). I ran an univariate test in SPSS.
[image]

1. Is the **SD sigma within each group** the averaged SD of the 4 conditions?
2. is the **number of measurement** 4?
3. I am not sure what to out in **Corr among rep measures**, so I ran a bivariate correlation test in SPSS (Pearson, 1-tailed). I found the correlation between the 2 variables is 0. So I put 0 there. Am I correct?

by the way, have anyone read an experiment in which researchers found an insignificant result because the power is not enough (due to small sample size). I want to read an article like this since I am having the exactly same situation now.

Thank you so much! :)

Comment: You will likely be interested in writing about [*post hoc* power analysis](http://stats.stackexchange.com/q/12118/1036).