# Can someone explain what a plim is in regression?

Tags: regression, probability, mathematical-statistics, econometrics

I know it has to do with consistency in the coefficients of the explanetory variable but I just don't understand what it is or how we use it. My professor doesn't explain it well, and I cant seem to find a good source that can explain it well. Can someone help?

Comment: This appears to be fully explained in answers to [what is a complete list of the usual assumptions for linear regression](http://stats.stackexchange.com/a/16460).

Answer (score 1):

Take a look around [page 19](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=7&ved=0CFwQFjAG&url=http://faculty.fuqua.duke.edu/~charlesw/s591/Methods/c02_Charlie/kennedy_chapter2.PDF&ei=VNOaUKHaNsWkiQKRuoGQCw&usg=AFQjCNFAxWU82F4gzeUfK8_6H04_f9ejTA&sig2=LUF0uADijPd7U4vtywTVPg&cad=rja) of Peter Kennedy's *Guide To Econometrics*. In particular Figure 2.5 has a nice graphical presentation of what it means for the asymptotic distribution of an estimator to become concentrated on a particular value $k$ as the sample size grows. If the probability limit $k$ happens to be the true population value, you get consistency. That is the clearest explanation I know, though it is admittedly a crude oversimplification.