# Consequences of non normal-distribution multiple regression

Tags: regression, p-value, assumptions

I am currently writing my thesis using multiple regression.
However my data does not meet the regression assumption of normal distribution.

I want to describe that, due to the non normal distribution, the interpretation of the data is limited. I don't want to transform the data, i just want to say what the impact of the non normal distribution on my regression results (N =110) is.

If have been googling a lot, however only found the assumptions, but never really consequences when i still conduct my tests.

Does any of you know, what the consequences of non normal distribution for my regression results are? And also very important, which paper could be cited?

I would be very grateful for your hint!

Comment: Does anybody actually have normal data? How non-normal are we talking? With 110 observations mild non-normality may be of little consequence. If you're constructing prediction intervals it might matter a lot more. What kinds of inference were you performing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Regression does not assume normal distribution of your *data*.

Regression assumes normal distribution of the *errors* about predicted values of $y$ (i.e. $y_{i} - \hat{y}$).

You're welcome.

Comment: Good concise statement. Much more is easily accessible on this site e.g. http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/16381/what-is-a-complete-list-of-the-usual-assumptions-for-linear-regression/16460#16460

Comment: Thanks Alexis - thats what I meant. So concluding from Nick's link, when my errors are not normally distributed, my beta values are wrong? Is that right? And why is this so?

Comment: Yes. See for example, Anscombe, F. J. (1973). Graphs in statistical analysis. *The American Statistician*, 27(1):17–21 for an example of what statistical outliers can do to bias regression estimates. However, the normality assumption may not be the worst assumption to violate, particularly for large data sets: Lumley, T. and Emerson, S. (2002). The Importance of the Normality As- sumption in Large Public Health Data Sets. *Annual Review of Public Health*, 23:151–69.

Comment: From Lumley and Emerson: "_In small samples most statistical methods do require distributional assumptions_". Yes, it's different when you can rely on asymptotic normality, but... is Jay interested in small or large samples? Is N=110 a large sample?

Comment: Hence, "particularly for large data sets."