# Regression with Dummy Variable

Tags: regression, categorical-data, assumptions

If I will analyze dummy-variables as the independent variable and interval/ratio data as the dependent variable using dummy-regression, do i need to meet some assumption before i analyze the data?

Comment: This question has been asked in one form or another many times on this site. See http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/16381/what-is-a-complete-list-of-the-usual-assumptions-for-linear-regression for example