# Confusion in terminologies for simple linear regression model

Tags: regression, correlation, sampling, covariance, estimators

Please go through my draft summary below and let me know if my conventions are correct, comprehensible, and non ambiguous.

## Simple Linear Regression Model

Let given *observed* sample set be $\{(x_1,y_1),(x_2,y_2), \cdots (x_N,y_N)\}$.$X,Y$ are random variables that can take on any value $(x_i,y_i)$
within range of sample set.

### Population Regression Function, PRF

Given a population $(X,Y)$ we **hypothesize** underlying population has
a regression line as follows. The **conditional expectation** is

$$\begin{aligned}
    & E(Y|x) = \beta_0 + \beta_1x       & \text{PRF}  
    \end{aligned}$$

The above equation is called Population Regression Function, PRF.
Including the error $\varepsilon$, the *prediction* of dependent
variable would be

$$\begin{aligned}
    & Y = E(Y|x) + \varepsilon  & \text{Prediction}  
    \end{aligned}$$

which is called simple linear regression model for population.

- RVs: $X, Y|x, \varepsilon$
- Parameters $\beta_0, \beta_1, \mu_X, \sigma_X^2, \ \ \mu_{Y|x}, \sigma_{Y|x}^2\ \ \sigma^2$

### Sample Regression Function, SRF

#### Point Estimates from single SRF

Given a sample set $(X,Y)$, we **estimate** underlying population has a
regression line as follows.

\begin{align}
& \hat{Y} = \hat{\beta_0} + \hat{\beta_1}x & \text{SRF, Estimator of RV } E(Y|x), \text{ not } Y \\
& \hat{\varepsilon} = Y - \hat{Y}   & \text{Estimator of RV } \varepsilon
\end{align}

For given sample $(x_i, y_i)$ from sample set $(X,Y)$, a **fitted
value** and **residual** are $$\begin{aligned}
    & \hat{y_i} = \hat{Y}(x_i)= b_0 + b_1x_i    & \text{Fitted value, Estimate of RV } E(Y|x) \text{ at } x_i  \\
    & \hat{\varepsilon_i} = y_i - \hat{y_i}           & \text{Residual, Estimate of RV } \varepsilon \text{ at } (x_i,y_i)
    \end{aligned}$$

Using OLS,

$$\begin{aligned}
    & \hat\beta_1 = \dfrac{\sum_{(x,y)}(y - \overline{Y})(x - \overline{X}) }{\sum_{x}(x - \overline{X})^2}  & \text{Slope RV, Estimator of Parameter } \beta_1  \\
    & \hat\beta_0 = \overline{Y} - \hat\beta_1\overline{X}  & \text{y-intercept RV, Estimator of Parameter } \beta_0 \\
    & b_1 = \dfrac{\sum_{i}(y_i - \overline{y})(x_i - \overline{x}) }{\sum_{i}(x_i - \overline{x})^2} & \text{Slope constant, Estimate of Parameter } \beta_1  \\
    & b_0 = \overline{y} - b_1\overline{x}  & \text{y-intercept constant, Estimate of Parameter } \beta_0 
    \end{aligned}$$

- $\hat{\beta_0},\hat{\beta_1}$ are estimators of $\beta_0,\beta_1$
  for *any sample set*. $b_0,b_1$ are estimates of $\beta_0,\beta_1$
  for *given sample set*
- Estimators: $\hat{\beta_0}, \hat{\beta_1}, \hat{X}, \hat{Y},  \hat{\varepsilon}$
- Estimates:
  $b_0, b_1, \overline{x}, s_X^2, \overline{\hat{y}}=\overline{y}, s_{Y|x}^2=s^2$

The entire draft is available [here](https://www.scribd.com/document/393581702/29-Regression-Ext)

**Ref:**

1. Devore's book [here](https://fac.ksu.edu.sa/sites/default/files/probability_and_statistics_for_engineering_and_the_sciences.pdf)
2. Gujarati's Basic Econometrics [here](https://himayatullah.weebly.com/uploads/5/3/4/0/53400977/gujarati_book.pdf).

**Update 1:** As per whuber advice, I also have started separate distinct to the point question, with first one [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/378078/doubt-about-state-of-predictor-variable-in-prf-and-its-implications-regression). Looking forward for further feedback. (For eg, we could either quash this question and continue there, or bring one of them (or first), here modifying this question)

**Update 2:** Specific split up questions (including first one just for entirety).
1. [Doubt about Predictor Variable](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/378078/202481)
2. [Is residual an estimate of error](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/378093/202481)
3. [Characterizing estimator,estimate separately](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/378241/202481)
4. [Why SSE has (n-2)df - not duplicate](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/378407/202481)

Comment: I think this isn't an on topic question for SE. It's a bit of an XY problem. Honestly, regression terminology is hard to grapple with, but your attempt to reinvent the wheel here is unfathomable for me. A lot of unnecessary terms, and misuse, and incorrect assumptions. Sxy is, for instance, not a constant because it has variance.

Comment: The first section of this post is addressed at https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/16381/what-is-a-complete-list-of-the-usual-assumptions-for-linear-regression/16460#16460: looking at that might be a good start.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/86062/discussion-on-question-by-paari-vendhan-confusion-in-terminologies-for-simple-li).