# Colinearity counter example in Linear Regression

Tags: regression, linear

I am trying to understand the colinearity assumption for linear regression. I have produced this counter example which I can't explain:

Suppose we are modelling the sales of a shop by the sea and on any given day the shop sells two items, buckets and spades. Buckets cost £2 and spades cost £1. The relationship should be:

```
Y = 2B + S
```

There is clearly colinearity going on between the variables buckets and spades as they are generally bought together.

Any help?

Comment: Welcome to CV.  Linear regression has no "colinearity assumption."  Please see https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/16381 for a discussion of the assumptions. Regardless, what is your question?