# proportional odds (PO) ordinal logistic regression model as nonparametric ANOVA that controls for covariates

Tags: nonparametric, ordinal-data, predictor

I have continuous response variables that are parameters returned by a [reinforcement learning+working memory model](https://ccn.berkeley.edu/pdfs/papers/Collins_etal2014JoN_RLWMSchizophrenia.pdf). My group variable includes three levels: healthy controls, unipolar depression, and bipolar depression.

I would like to compare the parameters between groups (for example, do people with unipolar depression have a lower reward learning rate than healthy controls), while controlling for age and gender. The parameters are not normally distributed and previous studies used non-parametric tests such as the Kruskal-Wallis H or Mann-Whitney U-test. I would like to control for age and gender, so I researched that the Wilcoxon-Mann-Whitney two-sample rank-sum test is a special case of the proportional odds (PO) ordinal logistic regression model.

Right now, I used the 'orm' function from the '[rms'package](https://github.com/harrelfe/rms) in R:

```r
orm(RL_alpha ~ GROUP_any_lifetime_MD + demographics_gender + 
    demographics_age, data = mydata_RLWM)
```

Does it seem like a valid approach? Are there any alternatives or additional checks?

I am new to the forum and I really appreciate any advice!

Answer (score 1):

The outcome variables don't need to be normally distributed for linear regression to work; what's important is that the *residuals* around the model predictions be well behaved. See [this thread](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/16381/28500) among others on this site.

That said, ordinal regression can be a useful tool for flexible modeling of outcomes. See Frank Harrell's [course notes](http://hbiostat.org/doc/rms.pdf) and [book](https://hbiostat.org/rms/) for details on types of ordinal regression models (e.g., proportional-odds versus continuation-ratio), the choice of distribution family (proportional odds uses a logistic family, but other choices are possible; see the help page for `orm.fit`), and ways to check, validate and calibrate models. Chapter 14 of the book has an extended presentation of how to apply ordinal regression, in a case study.

Comment: Thank you for the reply! The QQ plot showed strong violations of the normality assumption when I ran the linear regression and previous studies all applied non-parametric tests, so that's why I also want to use non-parametric tests in this situation. I also watched Frank Harrell's course on Youtube, but I will also check out the book! Thanks for sharing that!