Does H0:beta_1=0 in SLR assume normality of outcome which MIGHT NOT BE TRUE AT ALL?
Theoretical Simple Linear Regression Model under the Null Hypothesis
The theoretical simple linear regression model under the Null Hypothesis ($\beta_1 = 0$) is:
$$
Y_i = \beta_0 + \epsilon
$$
where $\epsilon \sim N(0, \sigma^2)$.
So essentially:
$$
Y_i \sim N(\beta_0, \sigma^2)
$$
Though I wonder if using the mean and standard deviation of $y_i$ would be more reasonable than using $\beta_0$ and $\sigma$ estimated from the original sample.
Doesn't this mean that $Y_i$ has to be normally distributed, which:

Is not included in the Simple Linear Regression (SLR) assumptions.
Might have very well been already rejected by our sample data, as long as the original $y_i$ aren't "normal enough".

If $H_0$ is truly $Y_i \sim N(\beta_0, \sigma^2)$, we can just test it by quantifying how much the KDE of $y_i$ values deviates from a perfect normal distribution and giving a p-value to that specific statistic. No regression needs to be involved here.
One might argue that a better null hypothesis would be that the values of predictor variables don't matter for the outcome, and simulate samples under the null hypothesis by shuffling the values of $x_i$. But then again, this would be a $H_0$ not just for linear association but any possible association as well.
In that case, if we fit linear forms to every simulated sample generated through shuffling to create a null sampling distribution of the slope, and find that our observed slope has a p-value smaller than 0.05:

Do we reject the hypothesis that there’s no linear association (which is what we want)?
Or are we only able to reject that there’s no any association (which is less helpful, since we don’t yet know if it’s linear)?

Maybe the $H_0: Y_i \sim N(\beta_0, \sigma^2)$ actually means there’s some other association that requires normality of the outcome, just that it’s not linear, so $\beta_1 = 0$?
This is kind of 2 questions at once so sorry if it's a bit confusing. I would also love some clarification of what is the beta_0 and sigma under H_0:beta_1=0 since our professor did not specify on that in class.

You lost me at "not included in the Simple Linear Regression (SLR) assumptions," because that's explicitly what you had supposed earlier about $\epsilon.$  From there you veer into issues tangential to SLR, which does not concern testing Normality hypotheses: your original $H_0$ concerns only the value of $\beta_1.$  These inconsistencies make it difficult to follow the rest of your post or even figure out what your question might be.

I mean that the original values of the sample outcome should not have to be normally distributed, however this is what $$
Y_i \sim N(\beta_0, \sigma^2)
$$
seems to suggest?

Your form for simple linear regression omits the predictor variable $x$. You should write instead $Y_i = \beta_0 x_i + \epsilon$ for an individual observation $i$, with corresponding changes to subsequent formulas.

You may also want to check this answer out: https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/16460/97844

But under the null hypothesis the slope is 0 so $x_i$ dont matter?

This looks circular: it is you who asserts $\epsilon$ must be Normally distributed in the first place. // Another issue, much subtler, is that a null hypothesis occurs within the context of a statistical model; but within that context, it asserts (in this case) only that $\beta_1=0.$  The distribution of $\epsilon$ is part of the context but not part of the null hypothesis.

Short answer: the outcome variable doesn’t need to be normally distributed, only the error terms do. So no, H0: B1 = 0 doesn’t assume Y is normally distributed. It doesn’t assume this because it frequently isn’t. Income, for example, is rarely normally distributed. But the statistical inference is still valid. You can transform the data to make it easier to interpret, but in any case, the simple answer is no.
“ One might argue that a better null hypothesis would be that the values of predictor variables don't matter for the outcome”. That is the literal standard definition (albeit worded differently ).  No association between predictor and outcome = predictors don’t matter to the outcome. More generically, it’s the non-existence of the alternate hypothesis. E.g. the choice between 12 vs 24hr clock is not associated with precision of the clock has the same meaning as the clock being 12 hr or 24hr doesn’t matter for the clock’s precision. Both are null hypotheses. Neither is better as they are different ways of saying the same thing.
“Maybe the H0:Yi∼N(β0,σ2) actually means there’s some other association that requires normality of the outcome, just that it’s not linear, so β1=0?”
This is predicated on a false assumption that the outcome must be normally distributed. Also, in SLR the null only applies to linear relationships. Failing to reject the null in SLR doesn’t mean that no relationship exists, merely that there isn’t enough evidence to say with confidence that one exists. It is entirely possible that a linear relationship exists (a false negative) or that a nonlinear relationship exists.
It seems like you’re overthinking this (lord knows I’ve gone down that road many times before. ). But to summarize: null hypothesis is stating that a specific relationship doesn’t exist. In SLR it means that no linear relationship exists. SLR can’t test for nonlinear relationships.

Thanks! I understand now from practical pespective why outcome can't be normally distributed in most cases. From a theoretical pespective though, if we define SLR as $Y_i = \beta_0 + \beta_1 x_i + \epsilon_i \quad \text{ where } \quad \epsilon_i \sim \mathcal N\left(0, \sigma^2\right)$, and $H_0$ as $\beta_1$=0, doesnt this naturally result in $Y_i \sim \mathcal N\left(\beta_0, \sigma^2\right)$?

Ok, now I’m tracking. Theoretically speaking, assuming all assumptions are true, then yes. It would result in Y being normally distributed about B0. Xi may not be, but its distribution isn’t associated with Yi under the null hypothesis, so the only thing that would affect Yi is the intercept constant and the error terms.
