# How to choose an appropriate covariance structure for a simple one-way within-subjects RM ANOVA design?

Tags: anova, mixed-model, sas

It is postulated that one of the main issue is to find an appropriate covariance structure for repeated measures designs [[Ref1](http://faculty.washington.edu/heagerty/Courses/b571/homework/Littell-StatMed2000.pdf)]. SAS' [PROC MIXED](http://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/10.1002/1097-0258%2820000715%2919:13%3C1793::AID-SIM482%3E3.0.CO;2-Q/abstract;jsessionid=2E99763AFF7D4850C5824196F901CE4D.d03t01) contains [a number of covariance structures](http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/statug/63962/HTML/default/viewer.htm#statug_mixed_sect020.htm).

Despite *"many choices among models to fit to a given data set in the mixed model setting... [and] we must always remember that all models are wrong (because they are idealized simplifications of Nature), but some are useful* [[citation](http://www.stat.cmu.edu/~hseltman/309/Book/chapter15.pdf)]." there are different recommendations for choosing among the covariance models are known [[Ref2](http://www2.sas.com/proceedings/sugi30/198-30.pdf)], [[Ref3](http://www.jerrydallal.com/LHSP/repeat2.htm)].

I do experiments with simple one-way within-subjects RM ANOVA (balanced and unbalanced) design without a between-subject factor described [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/11887/5003).

My question is
*how is it important if I have a "**condition**" (*not time*) as a within-subject factor and how to choose an appropriate covariance structure in this case*?

Perhaps this is a strange case as I have a native substance and its chemical derivatives with *similar* molecular structures. So probably I have correlation caused by the substance itself?

Comment: Thanks for the references: I had read in Littell et al.'s "SAS for Mixed Models" [book](http://books.google.co.nz/books?id=z9qv32OyEu4C&printsec=frontcover#v=onepage&q&f=false) that using AIC might be a reasonable way to choose between two covariance structures **for otherwise identically specified models**

Answer (score 2):

If you have no basis for a particular correlation structure and the unstructured correlation option requires too many parameters, I would try two different ones to see if the results are sensitive to the choice .  In my experience they usually aren't sensitive. I would probably compare AR(1) to compound symmetry.

Comment: thank you for you suggestion. But what characteristics do I have to look at?

Comment: You just want to see the extent to which the results change depending on the choice of covariance structure.

Comment: OK. And the *minimal* Akaike Information Criterion is one of them. Right? (as noted by G.E.Dallal "[Choosing Among Covariance Structures](http://www.jerrydallal.com/LHSP/repeat2.htm)")

Comment: Not exactly.  AIC is a criterion to minimize when selecting between models. What I was referring to is really a subjective assessment of the change in fit or the change in the AIC if you want to look at it that way.