# Violated Normality of Residuals Assumption in Linear Mixed Model

Tags: mixed-model, lme4-nlme

I have a question regarding how concerned I should be regarding a potential violation from the normality of residuals assumption in a linear mixed model. I have a relatively small data set, and after fitting the model (using 'lmer' in R), a Shapiro-Wilks test reveals a significant deviation of the residuals from a normal distribution. Log-transformations of my variables do not deal with this satisfactorily.

In my search for a response how to deal with this, I encountered advice that tests of normality shouldn't be conducted [(see the answer to a similar question here)](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/32957/testing-normality-assumptions-for-linear-mixed-models-and-mixed-repeated-glm-a). Instead, it's suggested QQ-plots of random normal data with the same N as my residuals should be conducted to see whether the QQ-plot of my residuals is markedly different. Other advice I have found seems to suggest that inference appears to be robust to various violations of LMM assumptions 
[(see blog post here)](http://thestatsgeek.com/2014/08/17/robustness-of-linear-mixed-models/).

**My Questions**

1) If this was your data, would you be concerned about the lack of normality in the LMM residuals (see data & output below)?

2) If you are concerned, are you still concerned after the log-transformation (again, see data & output below)?

3) If the answer is "Yes" to both above, how could I deal with the non-normality of my residuals?

**Data & Non-Transformed Analysis**

```
# load relevant library
library(lme4)

#--- declare the data
study <- c(1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 5, 5, 6, 6,
           7, 7, 8, 8, 9, 9, 10, 10, 10, 10, 11, 11, 11, 11, 12, 12, 13, 13, 
           13, 13, 14, 14, 14, 14, 14, 14, 15, 15, 16, 16, 16, 16, 17, 17)

condition <- c(1, 1, 2, 2, 1, 1, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4, 4, 1, 1, 
               1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 1, 1, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
               2, 2, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 1, 1)

age <- rep(c(1, 2), times = length(study) / 2)

congruent <- c(937, 611, 1067, 611, 1053, 943, 1097, 1015, 1155, 974, 860, 594,
               910, 605, 912, 632, 998, 660, 1989, 1176, 1337, 936, 2657, 1234, 
               1195, 999, 1010, 634, 1205, 620, 1154, 909, 1425, 1172, 1388, 
               1084, 641, 407, 1429, 810, 909, 510, 1358, 802, 1132, 639, 
               1501, 703, 1471, 955, 1342, 631, 1178, 676, 1033, 723)

incongruent <- c(1025, 705, 1204, 705, 1119, 1008, 1184, 1046, 1225, 1013, 1308, 
                 895, 1234, 901, 1204, 854, 1177, 828, 2085, 1269, 1350, 929, 
                 2697, 1231, 1233, 1032, 1062, 679, 1263, 674, 1183, 914, 1458, 
                 1184, 1382, 1086, 632, 424, 1510, 871, 978, 568, 1670, 881, 
                 1395, 747, 1694, 795, 1504, 999, 2112, 948, 1494, 992, 1039, 
                 781)

data <- data.frame(as.factor(study), as.factor(condition), age, congruent, 
                   incongruent)

#--- LMM analysis

# center age
data$age <- scale(data$age, center = TRUE, scale = FALSE)

# fit
fit <- lmer(incongruent ~ congruent + (1|study) + (1|condition), 
            data = data, REML = FALSE)

# plot & test the residual
qqnorm(resid(fit))
qqline(resid(fit))
shapiro.test(resid(fit))

Shapiro-Wilk normality test

data:  resid(fit)
W = 0.74417, p-value = 1.575e-08
```

[image: Non-Transformed QQ-plot]

**Log-Transformed Data**

```
# do the log transform 
data$congruent <- log(data$congruent)
data$incongruent <- log(data$incongruent)

# fit again
log_fit <- lmer(incongruent ~ congruent + (1|study) + (1|condition), 
                data = data, REML = FALSE)

# plot & test the residual
qqnorm(resid(log_fit))
qqline(resid(log_fit))
shapiro.test(resid(log_fit))

Shapiro-Wilk normality test

data:  resid(log_fit)
W = 0.93241, p-value = 0.003732
```

[image: Log-transformed QQ-plot]

**Simulated Normal Distribution QQ-Plots**

Performing this recommended simulation my log-transformed QQ-plots do not look too dissimilar to ones generated from a true normal distribution with the same sample size as my data (N = 52):

```
set.seed(42)
par(mfrow = c(3, 3))
for(i in 1:9){
  x = rnorm(52)
  qqnorm(x)
  qqline(x)
}
```

[image: Resulting Figure]

Comment: What is the goal of the model? If it is the best forecast than normality does not matter. Only outliers do. There is a theorem that lm does not need normality for good estimators. If it is for a scientific paper then I would use bootstrapping for the null probabilities.

Comment: @keiv.fly Yes, it's for a paper. In a next step I want to see whether the "age" variable is required (so will add more model fits and test via anova).

Comment: @keiv.fly, (nonparametric) bootstrapping is a good idea but has to be done in a way that respects the structure of the data.  Making `condition` a fixed effect would help, then you could do hierarchical bootstrapping (i.e. resample studies with replacement, then resample values within studies with replacement)

Comment: @JimGrange Please correct me if I am wrong - shouldn't `x` be equal to `rnorm(56)` since there are 56 observations?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

My answer to your questions would be (1) "yes" (I would worry a bit about the initial degree of non-Normality), (2) "no" (log-transformation seems to have improved the situation), (3) N/A (since I'm not worried), but a few more things to try if you *are* worried would be:

- use `robustlmm::rlmer()` to do a robust LMM fit;
- try the fit without the points that give the most extreme residuals (try `lattice::qqmath(log_fit,id=0.1,idLabels=~.obs)` to identify them by observation number) and see if it makes much of a difference
- try another transformation to get closer to Normality (although I played around with this a little bit and it doesn't seem to help)

I'm a little surprised by the apparent mismatch between your sims (these examples look *farther* from Normality by eye) and the Shapiro test results (fairly strong evidence against the null hypothesis of Normality).

Comment: Thanks - your response to Q2 matches my gut feeling, so that is reassuring.

Comment: If there were some models where assumptions are violated and some where this is not the case - would you report all "normal" models by default and robust models  additionally (to verify "normal" models where violations are present) ? Or would you report only one model type for each case? @Ben Bolker

Comment: My preference is to report all the same model type, so if the assumptions were violated badly for some models/data sets, I would report robust model results (or whatever) for all cases.  But that's mostly a stylistic preference, I think.