# Calculating normality for a two way ANOVA with repeated measures

Tags: r, normal-distribution, anova, repeated-measures

I am trying to calculate if my residuals are normally distributed for my two way ANOVA with repeated measures on Rstudio.

However, all the tutorials I find seem to specific to one way within ANOVAs or two way between ANOVAs.

If anyone knows the R script to determine the residuals and graph them It would be very much appreciated!

Thank you

Comment: checking residuals is much the same for 1way/2way/... anova ...

Comment: Does this answer your question? [ANOVA assumption normality/normal distribution of residuals](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/6350/anova-assumption-normality-normal-distribution-of-residuals)

Comment: What does this have to do with RStudio?   And what is the nature of the repeats?  What sort of serial correlation pattern do you expect?  Why does two way ANOVA address that?

Answer (score 6):

The residuals from an ANOVA can be handled like any linear regression in R, in that once you run a saved object from an ANOVA or regression, you can typically obtain the residuals fairly easy and thus run a QQ Plot. Here is a quick way I borrowed from [this site](http://www.sthda.com/english/wiki/two-way-anova-test-in-r#check-the-normality-assumpttion), though I skipped a lot of the other stuff since it wasn't relevant:

```
#### Save Data as Object ####
my_data <- ToothGrowth

#### Create Second Factor ####
my_data$dose <- factor(my_data$dose, 
                       levels = c(0.5, 1, 2),
                       labels = c("D0.5", 
                                  "D1", 
                                  "D2"))
#### Run Two-Way ANOVA ####
res.aov <- aov(len
                ~ supp
                + dose, 
                data = my_data)
summary(res.aov)

#### Plot Residuals ####
plot(res.aov, 2)
```

Which should give you this QQ plot:

[image]

As someone else noted here, you can also plot a histogram of the residuals and see if they are normal as well.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to check the histogram of residuals:

```
hist(your_model$residuals)
```

If in top of that you want to explicitly test for normality:

```
shapiro.test(your_model$residuals)
```

But I would more carefully check the plot of standardized residuals vs Fitted values with:

```
plot(your_model)
```