# Clarification about ANOVA assumption of normality

Tags: anova, residuals, normality-assumption

A few quick definitions:

- An **error** is the difference between an observed value and the "true" value
- A **residual** is the difference between an observed value and the "predicted" value

---

Let's say we have three samples and want to conduct a 1-way ANOVA:

$$H_0: \mu_1 = \mu_2 = \mu_3 = \mu$$

In order words, our null hypothesis is that all 3 samples were taken from the same population with mean $\mu$. Thus, $\mu$ is the "true" value. And I guess the grand mean of all the samples, $\bar{Y}$, is the "predicted" value.

According to Wikipedia, one of the assumptions of ANOVA is that the distributions of the residuals are normal. I have a few clarifying questions:

1. Which residuals are these? Is it: $(Y_{ij}-\bar{Y})^2$? Or the residuals within each sample: $(Y_{ij}-\bar{Y_j})^2$? Or both?
2. Why is the assumption that the residuals are normally distributed and not the sample values themselves? In other words, why is the assumption that $(Y_{ij}-\bar{Y})^2$ is normally distributed, but not $Y_{ij}$?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [ANOVA assumption normality/normal distribution of residuals](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/6350/anova-assumption-normality-normal-distribution-of-residuals) Note that the residuals aren't squared. The "predicted" values involve the sample membership indexed by $j$, so it's necessarily the $Y_{ij} - \bar Y_j$ that are evaluated.

Comment: @Nova Note that the assumption is about the errors, not the residuals. Once that is clear, the relevant indices are obvious