ANOVA from summary statistics
I need some advice. I found this website https://statpages.info/anova1sm.html and the R package "HH" to conduct a one-way anova from summary statistics given the groups sample sizes, means and standard deviations or standard errors.
My questions is:
What are the disadvantages in comparison to a "normal" one-way anova (are there some information lost in the process affecting the interpretation of the anova-results or the strength of the test)?
Edit
Clarifying my question with a working example: Datasets with summery statistics from surface roughness (Probe = Material surface, mean = roughness). Underlying data are normally distributed
Dataset 1



independent variable
sample size
Mean
Standarddeviation
Normality




Probe a
10
0.150
0.020
yes


Probe b
10
0.170
0.050
yes


Probe c
10
0.230
0.030
yes



Dataset 2



independent variable
sample size
Mean
Standarddeviation
Normality




Probe d
10
0.180
0.060
yes


Probe e
10
0.240
0.050
yes


Probe f
10
0.230
0.090
yes



Anova on aggregated data from Dataset 1 and Dataset 2):



independent variable
sample size
Mean
Standarddeviation
Normality




Probe a
10
0.150
0.020
yes


Probe b
10
0.170
0.050
yes


Probe d
10
0.180
0.060
yes


Probe e
10
0.240
0.050
yes




Other than possibly a slight loss in precision due to rounding, none -- $(\hat\mu,\ \hat\sigma)$ is a joint sufficient statistic for $\mathcal{N}(\mu, \sigma)$.

As per the above comment, you should get the exact same values for F, or the p-value., etc. A few (minor?) caveats: you will not be able to evaluate the normality of the residuals (you will need to take it on faith; normality of the levels is not a sufficient condition), and the 2 tools you mention will not handle Welch ANOVA; so your sample sizes and/or your variances need to be "close". The reason it works is that the variance (of a level) is the average of the sum of square differences within (a level).

@jginestet and PBulls: Perfect, that's almost all I need to know. Thank you very much. Although I can't evaluate the normality of the residuals, is there an assumption I can make? For instance, if I have conducted separate ANOVAs on two normal distributed datasets, then aggregating the summary statistics of both datasets and run another ANOVA the assumption of normality of the residuals should hold true?

Unfortunately no; a mixture of normals (even with same mean) may not be normal. Only if the variances are (nearly?) equal (because it is no longer a mixture of 2 different normals; it is a larger sample of the same normal).

@jginestet: True, and I'm also unable to verify if the variances are equal. in that scenario. But let me clarify my example: each of my 2 datasets has 3 independent variables tested for the same dependent variable (dataset 1: a, b, c; dataset 2: d, e, f). Each variable has the same group size, and the dependent variable is normally distributed. I conduct ANOVA based on summary stats for a, b, d, and e.  I assume normality since i did not mix the variables and use Hartley's Fmax to check variances.

If your groups in the one-way ANOVA have equal sample sizes, inequality of variances does not matter very much. But I am not sure I follow what you wrote; you say you have 3 independent variables; a one-way ANOVA is done with 1 independent categorical variable, which has several levels. Are your a,b,c,d,e,f different levels of the same dependent categorical variable? IS that what you meant? In this case, no pblm with unequal variances if you have the same # of observation for each level (a,b,...) of the dependent variable, Otherwise, please clarify.

@jginestet: I give you a working example in my original question (see section after EDIT)

Thanks for clarifying. So you have 1 independent variable (probe type), with several levels. The fact that all samples (of size 10) are normal is neither a necessary nor a sufficient condition (in spite of what you may read uin a lot of places). It is the residuals which need to be normal. The variances are not equal (lowest is .0004, largest is .0036, a factor of almost 10). W/o the raw data, you can not assess normality of the residuals. Wrt Welch ANOVA, even though the varainaces are different, your samples have the same size, so there is no issue.

See here for a discussion of normality of the residuals, not raw data https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/6350/anova-assumption-normality-normal-distribution-of-residuals
