How to Analyze Data with Very Rare Detection Events?
I am analyzing the distribution of particles by size in several specimens. I need to determine if there is a statistical difference in mean particle count between two groups of specimens (n=50 per group).
The data is collected by measuring particles that fall into certain size bins. Aka. >5um, >15um, >30um, etc. For the largest size bin (>500um), it is very rare to detect a particle. In about 20 of 100 specimens a particle is detected; the rest not. For my specific specimens, there was never more than one >500um particle detected per specimen. This results in the data being non-normal by Anderson-Darling. For all other particle sizes, the distribution is normal.
I want to be able to conduct ANOVA across all of the specimens in each particle size bin to determine if the mean are significantly different. This approach, of course, is not applicable if the data is non-normal.
Would it be appropriate to assume that, despite what the sample data says, the real distribution of the population of larger particle sizes also follows a normal distribution like the smaller sizes?

One issue with the question is that normality of the marginal distributions is not a required assumption for using ANOVA; it is normality of the residuals which is required. Which may very well apply in your case. I am also a bit confused about exactly what you measure; you talk about counts (i.e. number of particles in each bin?). But then you want to compare means? Means of counts? means of sizes (by bin)? Or you just mean counts? You also talk about specimens; does a specimen contain many particles? Or just 1? If you could clarify the terminology, that would help us help you.

Hello, yes, to clarify: we test 1 specimen at a time which releases many particles which are classified into size bins as specified. I then want to analyze the mean particle counts in each size bin between two different groups of specimens (aka, n=20 specimens in the treatment group vs n=20 specimens in the control group).

@jginestet I was under the impression that normality of the data is a requirement for ANOVA analysis, is this not correct? Anderson-darling of the residuals gives a p-value of <0.005, so very much not normal in any case.

You will find a thorough answer here: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/6350/anova-assumption-normality-normal-distribution-of-residuals. I will just quote one comment "You can pretty much ignore anything else those sources say if they claim the raw data needs to be normally distributed." Normality of the raw data is neither sufficient, nor necessary.

I decided to analyze the data as a Bernoulli distribution where my criteria are either "no particles" or "one or more particles" and using Fisher's Exact Test to determine the if the frequency of detections was significantly different between samples. For the other size bins, I abandoned ANOVA and simply did several two-way T-tests.

The last part of my question was never answered however, and I am curious as to whether or not it is appropriate to analyze a non-normal sample distribution as if it were normal if you are quite sure that the real population distribution is normal. Thanks.
